# Convert Free base to 2HCl form

Tags: organic-chemistry

I've been using this drug SID 347829124 - PubChem in my experiments from a vendor that supplied it as a $\ce{. 2HCl}$ version, and I switched to another supplier that has a free base instead. The two compounds have different solubility  in water and it would be desirable for me to obtain the $\ce{. 2HCl}$ form to avoid using $20\%$ dimethylformamide to solubilize the free base powder. I thought that using water with a stochiometric quantity of $\ce{HCl}$ would do the trick, but if somebody from the community could confirm this it would be very helpful.

Comment: Yeah, it should work.

Comment: If you want the dihydrochloride you need to use 2 molar equivalents of HCl.

Comment: It is not clear to me why 2 equivalent of HCl are needed though, there seems to be just one OH group highlighted in red capable of dissociation, why is there another oxygen atom highlighted?

Answer (score 2):

It should work but it is not guaranteed and will depend on application. Drug efficacy is [sensitive to the polymorph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_(materials_science)#In_pharmaceuticals) of the drug and for that reason, a slight change in manufacturing requires a complete redo of any certification process. I assume you are not in the manufacturing business, but it is something to consider and be aware of that your results may vary just by this simple change.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The efficacy is the same and I use the drug for in vivo research on mouse models.